# docker-machine stop command kills all my containers

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I am using docker-machine, and I created a VM with VirtualBox driver. I would like to pause my machine without killing all the running docker dontainers in that machine. Is this possible to do somehow? I would like to resume my machine, and resume all my containers that were running.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to do it as long as you use `Pause` or `Save State` on Virtualbox.  When you use `Pause` or `Save State` on VirtualBox all of your 'run' state is stored on the disk and then when you `Unpause` or `Restart` that 'run' state is restore from disk. Tried it myself and it works great.

[image: Save State/Pause]

This equivalent to using 'Suspend' on VMware.

Answer (score 5):

you can run :

- Stop All docker machines : `docker-machine stop $(docker-machine ls --format "{{.Name}}")` (edited)
- Start All docker machines :: `docker-machine start $(docker-machine ls --format "{{.Name}}")` (edited)
- Stop a machines : `docker-machine stop "<machine-name>"` (edited)
- Start a machines :: `docker-machine start "<machine-name>"` (edited)

Comment: Personally I prefer the docker-machine stop <machine-name> option presented here, over the answer selected as the "most correct" using the vmware interface, as it feels you are staying within the docker boundaries and not using the vmware way (if is not necessary), allowing you to practice, and memorize, the docker-machine, docker and docker-compose commands more. Thanks @ahmad

Answer (score 4):

Or from the command line:

```
VBoxManage controlvm YOURDOCKERMACHINENAME savestate
```

To resume:

```
docker-machine start YOURDOCKERMACHINENAME && eval $(docker-machine env YOURDOCKERMACHINENAME)
```